# What is the index of a singular regular point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading [this](https://www.edleaver.com/Misc/EdLeaver/Publications/AnalyticRepresentationForQuasinormalModesOfKerrBlackHoles.pdf) paper. At page 287 says that for the equation

$$r(r-1)\psi_{,rr}+\psi_{,r}+\left[ \dfrac{\omega^2r^3}{r-1}-l(l+1)+\dfrac{\epsilon}{r} \right]\psi=0$$

there are three singular points: two regular $r=1$, $r=0$ and one irregular at $\infty$. Then it says that the index of  $r=0$ is $1\pm\sqrt{\epsilon+1}$ and for $r=1$ it is $\pm i\omega$. What are those indices and how do I calculate them?

Comment: Anyone? I am really stuck on this, I can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the denominators
$$
r^2(r-1)^2y''+r(r-1)y'+[ω^2r^4−l(l+1)r(r-1)+ϵ(r-1)]y=0
$$
The lowest power terms of each coefficients around $r=0$ are
$$
r^2y''-ry'-ϵy
$$
As Euler-Cauchy equation this has the characteristic equation $0=m(m-1)-m-ϵ=(m-1)^2-1-ϵ$ so that the basis solutions are $r^{1\pm\sqrt{1+ϵ}}$.

The lowest order terms in an expansion $r=1+s$ around $r=1$ are
$$
s^2y''+sy'+ω^2y
$$
so that the characteristic equation $0=m(m-1)+m+ω^2=m^2+ω^2$ has the roots $m=\pm iω$.

> In a **Frobenius power series expansion** the above characteristic equations would be the **indicial** equations determining the leading power in $y(r)=r^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nr^n$ and $y(1+s)=s^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ns^n$.

Comment: Could you provide a reference?

Comment: Just any text book on differential equations containing the [Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method), the wiki page mentiones Teschl.